# WLS doesn't start anymore (JDeveloper)

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

Whenever I try to start the IntegratedWebLogicServer using the JDeveloper 12c on Windows 10 I get the following error:

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[Starting IntegratedWebLogicServer.]
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
"C:\WINDOWS\system32" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.
Process exited.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]
```

Apparently `C:\WINDOWS\system32` is invalid. I already tried reinstalling the JDeveloper.

My Environment Variables are set the following:

- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
- MW_HOME_12210=C:\oracle\product\12.2.1.0\middleware

Also I'm not able to check my logfiles under 
`C:\Usersname\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs` because the logs folder doesn't get created.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here.

> ";"C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wbem" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden."

After upgrade to win10 I got the same error.
Fixed it by deleting some entries at the User-Path-Variable. After changing this the WLS has started.

But be carefull and **Backup** all of your settings **before you delete/modify** it.

Comment: Interesting might have been what entries you've deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you retroactively over such a long period of time which settings I have deleted.